# Having problem converting big file of PDF to docx

Tags: c#

I have almost 900mb of PDF file and I want to convert it to documents or .docx

I've use sautinsoft.pdfFocus

Using this code

```
string pdfFile = @"d:\Coffee Table Book NPPNP (1).pdf";
string wordFile = @"d:\sample.docx";

// Convert PDF file to DOCX file 
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

f.OpenPdf(pdfFile);

if (f.PageCount > 0)
{
    // You may choose output format between Docx and Rtf. 
    f.WordOptions.Format = SautinSoft.PdfFocus.CWordOptions.eWordDocument.Docx;

    int result = f.ToWord(wordFile);
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    // Show the resulting Word document. 
    if (result == 0)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(wordFile);
    }
}
```

After running this code the application get laggy.

And how do I know if how many pages where converted?

Comment: I think you can`t do this(how do I know if how many pages were converted) with this approach and sautinsoft.pdfFocus.

Depends on your workflow it will be good to think about different approaches.

You can store the pdf on your disk and just trigger another middleware to process it and when it is ready set its status to 'ready' for example and show that to your users if thats the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
String inputPath = @"d:\Coffee Table Book NPPNP (1).pdf";
String outputPath = @"d:\sample.docx";
PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument(inputPath);
doc.ConvertToDocument(DocumentType.DOCX, outputPath);
```

Better to refer the above code to reduce complexity.